# Incompatible character encoding in simple Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, sinatra

I have a very simple Sinatra app running on Ruby 1.9.3 that uses ERB and markdown templates.  I've stripped it right down to demonstrate the problem.

This is running Sinatra 1.3.2 on Mac OS X Snow Leopard.  For the markdown I'm using rdiscount 1.6.8.

The main Ruby file contains

```
get '/services' do
  erb :services
end
```

The services.erb file has the following in it

```
<%= markdown :'content/service1' %>
£
```

Inside the markdown file I have just a single line

```
£
```

When I run the Sinatra app and load the 'services' page I get the exception `Encoding::CompatibilityError at /services incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT` on the second line of the ERB file (the one containing just the '£').

I've done lots of Googling and I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening.  The ERB and markdown files are UTF-8 on my local disk, but obviously they are being loaded by Sinatra and turned into strings, and I've no idea how to tell what encoding those strings are.

If I force Sinatra to use ASCII-8BIT (by adding `settings.default_encoding = 'ASCII-8BIT'` to the top of my main Sinatra Ruby file) then no exception is thrown but the '£' characters come out looking wrong.

Any pointers?

Comment: +1 for paring it down! A few questions: Have you added `#encoding: utf-8` at the top of each .rb file? Have you queried the `str.encoding` of the strings at various places? What version of Sinatra, what OS, and what Markdown library are you using?

Comment: Good questions.  I've edited my post.  Not sure where to get hold of `str` to call `.encoding` on it though?

Comment: And in answer to your other question, yes, I just tried putting `#encoding: utf-8` at the top of my single .rb file but I still get the exception.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an issue in [Tilt](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt), the templating system that Sinatra uses (and is being considered for Rails). Have a look at issues [#75](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt/issues/75) and [#107](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt/pull/107).

The problem is basically down to how Tilt [reads template files from the disk](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt/blob/1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb#L67) - it uses [`binread`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-binread). This means that the source string that is handed to the actual template engine has an associated encoding of `ASCII-8BIT`, which is basically saying that it’s unknown.

RDiscount has [code to set the encoding of the output to match the input](https://github.com/rtomayko/rdiscount/blob/1.6.8/ext/rdiscount.c#L34-L36), but this isn’t much help when the input encoding is `ASCII-8BIT`; the result is given the same encoding. The same thing (or something similar) happens with Kramdown, so simply switching won’t solve this.

This causes problems when the template has non-ascii characters (i.e. `£`) and you try to combine the result with other utf-8 encoded strings. If the template only contains only ascii characters, it is compatible with utf-8 and Ruby can combine the two strings. If not, you get the `CompatibilityError` that you see.

A possible workaround is to read the template files yourself, and pass in the resulting string with the correct encoding to Tilt:

```
<%= markdown File.read './views/pound.md' %>
£
```

By reading the file yourself with [`read`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-read) instead of `binread`, you can ensure it has the right encoding and so is compatible with the rest of the `erb` file.  You may want to read the file in once and cache the contents somewhere if you try this.

An alternative workaround would be to capture the output of the `markdown` method and use [`force_encoding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-force_encoding) on it:

```
<%= markdown(:pound).force_encoding('utf-8') %>
£
```

This is possible because although the encoding is `ASCII-8BIT`, you know that the bytes in the string really are utf-8 encoded, so you can just change the encoding.

Comment: Ah, that's good insight.  I'm much happier sticking with rdiscount then  (for now) and have a couple of good ways to tackle the problem now with confidence (since I understand what is going on behind the scenes).  Thanks @matt!